# composer require civicrm/cv will not install

Tags: cv, composer

I installed a new project using composer. First Drupal 10.1.6, next civicrm (following the install guide https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/drupal/), but when I try to run composer require civicrm/cv I get this:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - civicrm/cv dev-master requires symfony/process ^4 -> found symfony/process[v4.0.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v6.3.4 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - civicrm/cv[v0.1.0, ..., v0.1.1] require symfony/console ~2.3 -> found symfony/console[v2.3.0, ..., 2.8.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v6.3.8 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - civicrm/cv[v0.1.2, ..., v0.2.1] require symfony/console ~2.8 -> found symfony/console[v2.8.0-BETA1, ..., 2.8.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v6.3.8 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - civicrm/cv[dev-colemanw-patch-1, v0.2.2, ..., v0.3.13] require symfony/console ~2.8|^3 -> found symfony/console[v2.8.0-BETA1, ..., 2.8.x-dev, v3.0.0-BETA1, ..., 3.4.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v6.3.8 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - civicrm/cv[v0.3.14, ..., v0.3.48] require symfony/console ^4 -> found symfony/console[v4.0.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev] but the package is fixed to v6.3.8 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires civicrm/cv * -> satisfiable by civicrm/cv[dev-master, dev-colemanw-patch-1, v0.1.0, ..., v0.3.48].
```

What is wrong ? Your help would be appreciated,
Stefaan

Comment: You might try downloading the cv.phar file. That's how I installed cv. Not using composer. See these instructions: https://github.com/civicrm/cv